# How to create a PKCS12 blob with osx/iOS native security framework?

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, cryptography, commoncrypto

Is there a chance to generate a PKCS12 (.p12) blob **without using openssl** on mac/ios using the [Security framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157)?

Do i have to combine the X509,CA's and the RSA Key by my own or does the framework supports any higher level api?

I really could not find a way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but `SecKeychainItemExport` in the [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html), used with `kSecFormatPKCS12` should enable you to get a PKCS#12 blob (assuming that your private key and certificate are already in the keychain).

Comment: Not available on iOS.

Answer (score -2):

There are some online options available like [Mobundler.com](http://mobundler.com) which let you create p12 bundle without a Mac or OpenSSL.